# Erro na chamada de uma API

Tags: javascript, api

Estou estudando javascript puro e chamadas de api. Meu código está dando esse erro:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: users.forEach is not a function
  at renderUsers
```

```
async function getUsers() {
    let url = 'https://frontend-intern-challenge-api.iurykrieger.now.sh/products?page=1';
    try {
        let res = await fetch(url);
        return await res.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

async function renderUsers() {
  let users = await getUsers();
  let html = '';
  users.forEach(user => {
      let htmlSegment = `<div class="user">
                          <img src="${user.image}" >
                          <h2>${user.name} ${user.description}</h2>
                          
                      </div>`;

      html += htmlSegment;
  });

  let container = document.querySelector('#mostrar');
  container.innerHTML = html;
}

renderUsers();
```

e o html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mostrar"></div>
    <script src="./api.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

acredito que entendi sua pergunta. O erro do qual você está recebendo se dá pelo motivo de você estar tentando acessar a função `forEach()` que não está presente no objeto `users`, pois o mesmo não é um array. A API que você informou está retornando um objeto JSON com conteúdo de produtos e não usuários. Mas, mesmo assim, você pode acessá-lo utilizando `users.products` (Este sim é um array). Ficando assim como exemplo:

```
async function getUsers() {
    let url = 'https://frontend-intern-challenge-api.iurykrieger.now.sh/products?page=1';
    try {
        let res = await fetch(url);
        return await res.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

async function renderUsers() {
  let users = await getUsers();
  let html = '';
  users.products.forEach(product => { //Alterei o objeto acessado para users.products, ou seja, o array de produtos que é fornecido pela API.
  //Aqui você manipula cada item product do array products
      let htmlSegment = `
                        <div class="products"> //Alterei a classe pois vi que você não está utilizando folhas de estilo CSS ainda.
                          <img src="${product.image}" alt="Produto"/>
                          <h2>${product.name} ${product.description}</h2>

                        </div>`;
      html += htmlSegment;
  });

  let container = document.querySelector('#mostrar');
  container.innerHTML = html;
}

renderUsers();
```

Answer (score -2):

Lucas, a sua pergunta esta muito jogada de qualquer jeito, mas entendi o seu problema.

1 - O erro esta dizendo que `forEach` não é uma função de `users`, logo isso quer dizer que o valor que a variável `users` esta recebendo não é um array.

2 - Você esta usando a URL/API errada, nesta API você esta buscando por produtos: `https://frontend-intern-challenge-api.iurykrieger.now.sh/products?page=1`

O que resulta no seguinte JSON:
[image: print do devtools]

3 - Você notaria muito facilmente este problema investigando o devTools do seu navegador, analisando a requisição feita e vendo o resultado dela.
Isso pode transparecer preguiça, o que pode te gerar muitos downvotes aqui no StackOverflow.

Sugiro conhecer melhor as ferramentas de desenvolvimento disponíveis no navegador que utiliza, eu particularmente recomendo o Google Chrome, e tentar investigar mais por conta própria ao invés de postar uma pergunta e ficar aguardando uma resposta.

Comment: Eu sou bem iniciante em programação e aqui, por isso não sei como e quais os procederes corretos. Postei a pergunta pois não consegui resolver o problema.

Comment: @lucas-eugenio1990 Relax, imaginei que fosse o caso de ser iniciante. Minha intenção foi te orientar.

Comment: sim e eu te agradeço pelas dicas...vou procurar reformular melhor minhas dúvidas